# Rails: elegantly reduce duplication when using json to create objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I fetch data in `json` to create in my webapp, like this

```
response.each do |article|
    title = article['title']
    url = article['url']
    content = article['content']
    image_url = article['image_url']
    source = article['source']
    created_at = article['created_at']
    twitter_share = article['twitter_share']
    facebook_share = article['facebook_share']
    pocket_share = article['pocket_share']
    article = Article.new(title: title, url: url, image_url: image_url, content: content, created_at: created_at, source: source,
                    twitter_share: twitter_share, facebook_share: facebook_share, pocket_share: pocket_share)
    if article.save
      puts article.title
    end
  end
```

As you can see, there are a lot of duplications, how can I elegantly reduce these duplications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that article is a hash, so you can simple do

```
response.each do |article|
  article = Article.new(article)
  if article.save
    puts article.title
  end
end
```

If article contains other attributes you can strip them:

```
allowed = ['title', 'url', 'source']
response.each do |article|
  article = Article.new(article.slice(*allowed))
  if article.save
    puts article.title
  end
end
```

Comment: `keys` is how you get an array from the keys of a Hash. Since `allowed` is already an array, it first off doesn't have a `keys` method like a Hash would, and since it is an already, it is unnecessary. The splat operator (`*`) is what you need to turn the array into a list of args for the method.

Comment: I think it should be `article.slice(*allowed)`?

Answer (score 2):

Why don just use hash you get to create new aricle

```
  response.each do |article|
    new_article = Article.new(article)
    if new_article.save
      puts new_article.title
    end
  end
```

Comment: I think it is dangerous to create article from uncleared hash, dangerous values may be present.

Comment: there're some addtional info that I do not want to include, speficically, there is an `id` attribute passed into. How can I deal with this?

Comment: this is what `slice` is used for in Rails.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code:

```
def permitted_article_attrs_hash(hash)
  hash.dup.keep_if do |key, value|
    %w(title url content image_url source created_at twitter_share facebook_share pocket_share).include?(key)
  end
end

response.each do |article|
  article = Article.new(permitted_article_attrs_hash(article))
  if article.save
    puts article.title
  end
end
```

Advantage of this code is that unpermitted values are removed from *article* hash.